# Upgrading Jetty 9.4.12 to 9.4.53.v20231009

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Project uses Jersey 2.29, but trying to update Jetty only. Jersey 3.0.12 contains Jetty 9.4.53.v20231009 dependency. Should Jersey be upgraded too?

Project uses authentication, including Kerberos via SpnegoLoginService and SpnegoAuthenticator. Authentication worked with Jetty 9.4.12.

With Jetty 9.4.53, receive the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)

Were there any changes to authentication code that were not backwards compatible? Should any changes be required of keytab and other authentication files, i.e. are there additional restrictions on keytabs?

Comment: Jetty 9 is at End of Community Support. - see https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/7958 - You should be using Jetty 12 at this point in time.  Also keep in mind the Security Advisories against Jetty 9 - https://eclipse.dev/jetty/security_reports.php

Comment: `SpnegoLoginService` was deprecated 6 years ago around Jetty 9.4.13.v20181111, replaced with `ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService`.  Jetty 10 completely removed `SpnegoLoginService`.  Jetty 12 overhauled SNEGO authentication to not require Servlet and work on all protocols, and calls it `SPNEGOLoginService`.

Comment: Added:
HashLoginService authorizationService = new HashLoginService(DOMAIN_REALM, System.getProperty("spnego.properties"));
ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService spnegoLoginService = new ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService(DOMAIN_REALM, AuthorizationService.from(authorizationService, ""));

But “[main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService - Retrieving credentials for service null/server.domain.com” has null instead HTTP